# How to calculate the sum of repeated elements in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and stuck on a problem from last one week. 
I am getting dynamic weekly values for different groups.

My target is to caculate the sum of values for each group which is doable through filter, but I am not able to figure out how to re-calulate the weeklyvalues if I change the value of sum. What I have done so far:

**Controller:**

```
app.controller("CalculationController", [
"$scope", "calculationService", function ($scope, calculationService) {
    getGroups();

    function getGroups() {
        calculationService.GetGroups().success(function(groups) {
            $scope.groups= groups;
            console.log(groups);
        }).error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = "Error Occured: " + error.message;
            console.log($scope.status);
        });
    }$scope.getTotal = function () {
        var groupTotal = []; 
        var total = 0; // hold the total for week
        var totalPerGroup = 0;
        var totalPerGroupArr = [[], []]; //array to store total values Per Group
        var groups = $scope.groups; //getting the data of groups in a variable.
        var totalCostForEachWeekPerMainGroup = [[], []]; //array to store total groups for each week            
        var totalGroupsCostPerGroup = []; //array to store the total cost per group
        totalCostPerMainGroup = 0; //sum of all groups per Main Group


        for (var i = 0; i < trps.length; i++) {
            total = 0;
            totalPerGroup = 0;

            for (var j = 0; j < groups[i].WeeklyValues.length; j++) {
                totalCostForEachWeekPerMainGroup[j][i] = groups[j].WeeklyValues[i].Cost;
                totalPerGroupArr[i][j] = groups[i].WeeklyValues[j].Cost;
                totalPerGroup += totalPerGroupArr[i][j];
                total += totalCostForEachWeekPerMainGroup[j][i];
                totalCostPerMainGroup += totalCostForEachWeekPerMainGroup[j][i];
            }
            groupTotal.push(total);
            totalGroupsCostPerGroup.push(totalPerGroup);
            $scope.totalGroupsCostPerMainGroup = totalCostPerMainGroup;
        }


        //Percentage calculation for each week                        
        return groupTotal;
    }
}]).filter('sumCalculation', function () {
return function (data, key) {
    if (typeof (data) === 'undefined' || typeof (key) === 'undefined') {
        return 0;
    }
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        total += parseFloat(data[i][key]);
    }
    //$scope.sum = total;
    return total;
}});
```

**View:**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.Label("Main Group")</th>
                <th>@Html.Label("Group")</th>
                <th ng-repeat="w in numberOfWeeks" ng-cloak>W{{w}}-2016</th>
                <th>@Html.Label("Total")</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="(k, v) in GroupTotalPerMainGroupPerWeek"> // coming from another service
                <td>{{k}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td ng-repeat="cost in getTotal()">
                    {{cost}}
                </td>
                <td>{{totalGroupsCostPerMainGroup}}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="g in groups">
                <td></td>
                <td ng-cloak>{{g.GroupName}}</td>                    
                <td ng-repeat="c in g.WeeklyValues">
                    <input value="{{c.Cost}}" class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="c.Cost" ng-cloak/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input value="{{g.WeeklyValues|sumCalculation:'Cost'}}" class="form-control" string-to-number ng-model="Cost" type="number" ng-cloak/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

**Service:**

```
app.factory("CalculationService", ['$http', function ($http) {
var CalculationService= {};

CalculationService.GetGroups = function () {
    return $http.get("/Angular/GetGroups");
}

return CalculationService;}]);
```

What I want to achieve:

1. Calculate the sum of each value per group
2. Calculate the sum of all groups per week
3. Calculate the total sum of all groups
4. If i change the value of sum it should change the each weekly value accordingly
5. If i change the value of total (i.e. 1265 in example) it should recalculate the sum (value) of each group and each weekly value should be re-calculated:

The example of view is like:

GroupName------Week1Value------Week2Value------Week3Value------Sum

------------------ 312 ------------- 328 --------- 625-----------  1265

G1--------------  112 ------------- 113 --------- 300 ----------  525

G2--------------  200 ------------- 215 --------- 325 ----------  740